# Where to find Open API (Swagger) specification for the Confluence Server REST API?

Tags: swagger, openapi, confluence, confluence-rest-api

For the Atlassian Confluence Cloud REST API there is an Open API (formerly Swagger) specification available here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/swagger.v3.json

I was not able to find such an Open API specification for the Confluence **Server** REST API. Any hints as to where to find it are appreciated.

Comment: Did you ask Atlassian support? It's possible that the Server/DC versions don't have an OpenAPI definition.

Comment: @Helen No, but it's an idea if nobody knows something :)

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is old, but for anybody else who came come looking for an answer.

The Atlassian server/Datacenter version is based on Jersey. So there is a built-in implementation to generate the wadl file from your own instance.

replace your hostname of confluence, and just browse to the below URL.

/rest/api/latest/application.wadl

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found :)
I share my doc with you :

```
API Jira Cloud platform

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/intro/ 
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/swagger.json
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/swagger.v3.json
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/swagger-v3.v3.json


API Jira Software Cloud

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/rest/intro/  
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/swagger.json
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/software/swagger.v3.json


API Confluence Cloud

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/rest/v1/intro/
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/swagger.json 
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/confluence/swagger.v3.json 


Jira Service Management Cloud

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/rest/intro/ 
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/swagger.json 
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/service-desk/swagger.v3.json
```

Here is my script: in the “Postman environment” variables or in the “collection variables”, add:

```
baseUrl = https://XXX.atlassian.net
username = XXX@XXX.com
token = <token> https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security/api-tokens
```

In the “Pre-request Script” of the collection, add:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable(
    "base64", 
    btoa(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("username") + ":" + postman.getEnvironmentVariable("token"))
);
pm.request.headers.add({
    key: "Authorization",
    value: "Basic " + postman.getEnvironmentVariable("base64")
});
```

After adding this configuration: you must disable the “Authorization” configurations of each endpoint (because they are configured for the old Basic mode in login/password which no longer works deprecated)

Comment: Looks pretty good!